# Rearrange MATLAB table variables (Release 2016)

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

I have a table in MATLAB with variable titles equal to:

```
titles = {'TZ_1', 'TZ_2', 'TZ_3', 'DATE'};
```

Is there any way to move change the data to have the `DATE` before `TZ_1`?

```
titles = {'DATE', 'TZ_1', 'TZ_2', 'TZ_3'};
```

I can see `movevars` in the 2022 version, but I am currently running the 2016 version.

Any help would be appreciated - I am relatively new to MATLAB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by name

```
% Set up example data
t = table(1,2,3,4, 'VariableNames',{'TZ_1', 'TZ_2', 'TZ_3', 'DATE'})
% Specify the column ordering you want
titles = {'DATE', 'TZ_1', 'TZ_2', 'TZ_3'};
% Rearrange the table
t = t( :, titles );
```

You can of course do this without the intermediate variable

```
t = t( :, {'DATE', 'TZ_1', 'TZ_2', 'TZ_3'});
```

Extension:

If you just know you want `'DATE'` at the front regardless where it currently is in the order, you could do something like

```
titles = [{'DATE'}, setdiff(t.Properties.VariableNames, {'DATE'}, 'stable')];
t = t( :, titles );
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. It looks so simple when you see the solution. So frustrating

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with indexing. (If you look at the implementation of `movevars`, that is exactly what it does).

```
>> t = table(1,2,3,4, 'VariableNames',{'TZ_1', 'TZ_2', 'TZ_3', 'DATE'})
t =
  1×4 table
    TZ_1    TZ_2    TZ_3    DATE
    ____    ____    ____    ____
     1       2       3       4  
>> t(:,[4, 1:3])
ans =
  1×4 table
    DATE    TZ_1    TZ_2    TZ_3
    ____    ____    ____    ____
     4       1       2       3
```